# How to launch Expo XDE on Windows

Tags: exponentjs, expo

I just installed exponent version 11 on Windows.  After the installer completes, it automatically launches XDE.  But then I closed it.

I notice that there in the directory `~\AppData\Local\xde\app-2.10.0`, there is a suggestively named file called `Exponent XDE.exe`, and double-clicking seems to do the right thing, but I wonder: is this actually the recommended way to launch it, or is there, for instance, some command line argument I should be passing such that omitting it would cause subtle problems, or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XDE is launched without any special flags or arguments. You can create a simple shortcut that just launches the EXE and that will work.